# Make two html elements in single row.

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrtap 3.3.7, I have two elements input textbox and drop down menu.

Here is html:

```
<!-- input -->
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">      
    <div class="form-control col-xs-6" style="background-color:red">
        <select name="UNITS" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
        <option value="me">me</option>
        <option value="fe">fe</option>
        <option value="ki">ki</option>
        <option value="mi">mi</option>
        </select>
    </div>  

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6" style="background-color:green">
        <!-- <i class="fa fa-text-height"></i> -->
        <input type="edit" name="DISTANCE" id="distance" class="form-control input-group-lg" onkeyup="ValidateInput('distance')" placeholder='__#BUFFERDISTANCE#__'>    
    </div>
```

My question is how to make two elements above in same row?

And here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/31141/).

Answer (score 1):

I changed  `<div class="form-control col-xs-6" style="background-color:red">`into `<div class="form-group col-xs-6" style="background-color:red">`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- input -->
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">      
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6" style="background-color:red">
        <select name="UNITS" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
        <option value="me">me</option>
        <option value="fe">fe</option>
        <option value="ki">ki</option>
        <option value="mi">mi</option>
        </select>
    </div>  

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6" style="background-color:green">
        <!-- <i class="fa fa-text-height"></i> -->
        <input type="edit" name="DISTANCE" id="distance" class="form-control input-group-lg" onkeyup="ValidateInput('distance')" placeholder='__#BUFFERDISTANCE#__'>    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `col-xs-6` shouldn't also be a `form-control` because it's adding padding that's causing the columns to wrap. Make the select a `form-control` instead.

```
<div class="container">
         <div class="row">      
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:red">
                <select name="UNITS" class="form-control btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
                <option value="me">me</option>
                <option value="fe">fe</option>
                <option value="ki">ki</option>
                <option value="mi">mi</option>
                </select>
            </div>  

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6" style="background-color:green">
                <!-- <i class="fa fa-text-height"></i> -->
                <input type="edit" name="DISTANCE" id="distance" class="form-control input-group-lg" onkeyup="ValidateInput('distance')" placeholder='__#BUFFERDISTANCE#__'>    
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fryp6mdf/

Comment: thanks for post.my screen size is 250px.when I use your atitude i get horizontal scroll.Any idae how to prevent horizontal scroll?

Answer (score 0):

`form-control` class is adding `width: 100%` on that element so you have multiple solutions.

1. You can remove `form-control`
2. You can create one more element inside `col-xs-6` with `form-control` class [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/31144/)
3. Or you can set `width: 50%` [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/31143/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace form-control

```
<div class="form-control col-xs-6" style="background-color:red">
```

to form-group

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6" style="background-color:red">
```